# get/set Enhanced Protected Mode from c++ code

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I need to get and set "Enhanced Protected Mode" option enabaled in IE10 and later from C++ code.
I've googled a lot, but all solutions describe only how to do this manually not from code, but I need to do so in the installer of our IE add-on.

Any other solutions for this issue via registry, WMI or console command are very interesting too.

Can anybody help with this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Warning: This is not a supported behavior, and doing so may get your code flagged as malware by AV products or Microsoft's SmartScreen.

The "Enable Enhanced Protected Mode" checkbox in the Internet Control panel is controlled by the `Isolation` value under registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main`. It contains the value `PMEM` if AppContainers (EPM) should be used, or `PMIL` if non-EPM Integrity Levels (IL) should be used instead (default for IE10). There's no API to set this value as doing so is not supported.

Protected Mode itself is enabled or disabled on a per-Zone basis; the URLMon API [SetZoneActionPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is used to adjust a Zone's settings (for [URLAction_LOWRIGHTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to enable or disable Protected Mode for that Zone.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The value **named** `Isolation` has `PMEM` or `PMIL` as you desciberd. At least I can check this value and offer to the User to change it manually if needed.

Comment: On a clean Windows 8.1 install (shipped with IE11) the `Isolation` key is not longer present.

Comment: Did you try *changing* the setting?

Comment: By default, there is no entry. 8.1 / IE11 as shipped has it behave as if it PMEM by default... however a patch was released to make it treat it as PMIL by default.

Answer (score 3):

Did an update from 8.0 to 8.1 and there is no 'Isolation' key value name. But 'Enable Enhanced Protected Mode' is enabled. Looks like if the 'Isolation' value name is not present it has the same effect as having the value set to PMEM. The key value is created when you uncheck 'Enable Enhanced Protected Mode' and is updated each time you toggle the setting.